# jquery UI dialog not opening unless autoOpen is true

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried it a few times myself, doesn't work unless autoOpen is true. I copied the entire demo and pasted it on my local site and it won't open unless autoOpen is true.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo URL; ?>css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo URL; ?>js/jquery-ui.js" /></script>
```

URL being a constant for my public folder that has the css/js/images n stuff

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: true,
width: 400,
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
]
});

$( "#dialog-link" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The jQuery, copied from the demo. Located at the bottom of my page in script tags.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p> 
    <a href="#" id="dialog-link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        Open Dialog
    </a>
</p>
```

Last but not least the html, also copied from the demo.

Even if it does pop-up(when autoOpen is true), clicking the buttons won't close it.

My guess would be that it had something to do with the click event.

It didn't give any errors at first, but right now it gives "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. (anonymous function) n.event.dispatch n.event.add.r.handle "

It seems to error at $("#dialog").dialog("open"); when I clicked the row at the end of the error. prntscr.com/6i8734

Comment: That **could** mean you jQuery dialog Javascript file is broken or is an incompatible version. What about using `//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js`? Look at these examples: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated they are using jQuery 1.10.2 and you're using 2.1.3

Comment: @AlejandroIván I just tried changing the jquery and the jquery ui, it still does the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, another question: Are you using this inside the `document ready` event in jQuery? `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });`

Comment: @AlejandroIván I tried putting it in a document ready but then the text that is supposed to be in the dialog shows up on the website like [this](http://prntscr.com/6j3v5j)

Comment: Hmmm looks like a problem with your CSS more than the library itself... add the class `ui-dialog` directly: `<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" class="ui-dialog">`. If it doesn't work, maybe your CSS is not loading properly.

Comment: Look here's a direct link to one of the examples... look at its source code with your browser: http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/animated.html (note the jQuery UI CSS is from a specific theme called "smoothness").

Comment: I am also using the tooltip and that one works great. everything else aside from the css theme is the exact same. The pop-up looks fine when autoOpen is true so the css can't be it.